# Regex windows registry match in HTML document

Tags: regex

I have registry values that appear in the HTML document.
I try to mark every registry entry that appears in the example.
The problem is where the `<br>` character

https://regex101.com/r/BgNjh6/5

[image: Image example]

Comment: [Obligatory suggestion to not use regex on HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using a lookahead:

```
HKEY_\S+(?=<\/)
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/BgNjh6/3

Comment: Thanks. I also have a problem with the <bar> tag. please take a look: 
https://regex101.com/r/BgNjh6/5

Comment: For that you'll probably want something such as [`HKEY_\S+?(?=<\/|<br>)`](https://regex101.com/r/BgNjh6/6)

Answer (score 0):

**Tested**. Should Work

```
/HKEY_\S+(?=<\/)/g
```

`?=<` is called **Positive Lookahead Assertion**. It matches everything before itself unless you provide boundary.

Comment: Thanks. I also have a problem with the <bar> tag. please take a look: regex101.com/r/BgNjh6/5

Comment: what is your expectation?

Comment: post your question in stackoverflow